# Pass object as function arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have `class A` with some fields passed with `constructor` and `class B` that `extends class A`, the task is to create the `iterator` for `class A` that give me the possibility for pass it to `super` method (with spread operator or any another way).
`Object.entries()` doesn't help me. How can I do it?
I think this code is self-explanatory.

```
class A { 
    constructor(public a: string) { }
}


class B extends A {
    constructor(public b: string, a: A) {
        super(...Object.entries(a));
    }
}

/** can be new B('b', new A('a'));
 * But not the new B('b', 'a') actually 
*/
const b = new B('b', { a: 'a' });  
console.log(b); // expect to get {b: 'b', a: 'a'}
// actually get {b: 'b', a: ['a', 'a']}
```

Comment: `Object.entries` returns a list of arrays, which certainly doesn't match the `string` type of `a`. Not sure what exactly you expect here…?

Comment: @deceze I want to find the way to pass an object like an arguments list. I know that `Object.entries()` isn't working so I asked for any possible solution

Comment: Do you mean B should accept an object of class A as second param not anything else? or clarify your question

Comment: @PranoySarkar yes, and return the extended instance of class B

Comment: I think you misunderstand `extends`. You are not supposed to pass an instance of `A` in order to extend it. The extended instance of `A` is what the instance of `B` already is. Note also that an instance of `A` has no members (as you currently have it), so what did you expect to get from `Object.entries` anyway? `{ a: 'a' }` is not an instance of `A`, nor does the constructor of `A` define an `a` property...

Comment: @trincot I understand. The case than I will pass `A` object as  an argument is ok than there is no another solution than I can only is an `interface` from `A`, if here will be any alternate solution the variant than I pass an `A` object will be ok for me.

Comment: @SeregaTihovsky - I fixed an error in the second example in my answer after you accepted it, just wanted to call your attention to the fix. (I had `this.a = a;` where it should have been `this.a = x;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two answers for you:

- Answering what you asked, and
- Suggesting a different approach

#### Answering what you asked

I don't think you can do what you've described. Although you could have your `Symbol.iterator` function return the iterator of an array you create in the same order as `A`'s constructor's parameter list:

```
class A {
    constructor(public a: string) {
    }

    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return [this.a][Symbol.iterator]();
    }
}
```

...the problem is that the `super` call won't compile, TypeScript complains:

```
super(...a); // Expected 1 arguments, but got 0 or more.
```

I'm not seeing a workaround to that other than, of course, disabling that error with [`@ts-ignore`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments):

```
// @ts-ignore
super(...a); // Expected 1 arguments, but got 0 or more.
```

...which doesn't seem like a good idea. ([Live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XWAewHYQC4CcBXYXDfACgAdCAjEAS2GjAC5o996sBzASkRRoAvkkGoA2gGUAngFsaGEADp6uAKb4wpfAF1y-ZGiPR8a3IXxZo43AAt6EJWB1S5C5ao1aye3gG4xaBERUEgYACFoNQAPdSwAExh4QzRMHAJibSpaBiYaNg4ubgAaZjZYA0CjAHpq6AABXAgAWnpuLDI1KrQIQkoNciUhsH9A4NE0vGZoAF5oLDUAdzhyACIAMwwMVdHJ3GgaWfml6HC1mlXSkYDJxTUlEAxuchonf2ha6A2t1aA) on the playground.)

#### Suggesting a different approach

Even if you could do that, I wouldn't recommend it, it'd be fragile: If you change the order of the parameters in `A`'s constructor, you need to change your iterator to match. Keeping them in sync will be a maintenance pitfall.

Instead, I'd have the constructor be able to accept an instance of `A` and copy all of its properties:

```
class A {
    public a: string = "";
    constructor(a: string);
    constructor(obj: A);
    constructor(x: string|A) {
        if (x instanceof A) {
            Object.assign(this, x);
        } else {
            this.a = x;
        }
    }
}
```

The `super` call would be:

```
super(a);
```

[Live example on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQA4FcBGICWw0YAXNBAC4BOeAdgObQC80ARCwNwprAD2NFlTMHI9KAChJkqtOgEpOaaL35UhI8T2wArUrHldUygWtFiAHqQEyAPnsQHF0PADNo5pyrA1gAUx6u7ZEdg6AB5bR9hADpICDw6GjFyAAs8CAAaaDN9EOgAX2gfEAgfe1zFFLSYpiyFELyHBobQWOgAIUKzch8aABMYeCDuPmNhUyxcAmhsS2l6TMlAh0UITHQfcTActCakJCNyIhqaHwB3ODEWZx4eFn0D6eOz9svsFgX7kZ4QHyiQHjoYmwMXk0AA9GDWNdbkA)